# You have changed the settings for the XXXX. Would you like to apply these changes?

Tags: itunes

I have 3 iPhones and 1 iPad. These devices are listed on the left column on my iTunes on the mac. Suppose I have the first iPhone selected on that column. Every time I select another one, I see this annoying message:

```
You have changed the settings for the XXXX. Would you like to apply these changes?
```

where XXXX is the name of the device I had selected before.

The message has two choices. Don't Apply and Apply. Doesn't matter which one I choose I always see this message after selecting a new device there... and the message tell me about changes I did. I did nothing, just selected another device!!!!!!

Pretty annoying.

Is there a way to make this go away? Please save me from this annoyance!